# Cannot generate docker image of a Quarkus project

Tags: docker, compilation, native, h2, quarkus

I'm trying to generate a docker image of a simple API, using Quarkus and H2, using the following command:

```
./mvnw package -Pnative -Dquarkus.native.container-runtime=docker
```

And I'm receiving the error below. I have tried to fix it, withouth sucess.
Strange is, I can run my project just fine in dev mode with this command:

```
./mvnw compile quarkus:dev
```

Can somebody help me?

Error:

```
Error: could not find target method: public static io.quarkus.jdbc.h2.runtime.graal.CompareMode io.quarkus.jdbc.h2.runtime.graal.CompareMode.getInstance(java.lang.String,int,boolean)
com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError$UserException: could not find target method: public static io.quarkus.jdbc.h2.runtime.graal.CompareMode io.quarkus.jdbc.h2.runtime.graal.CompareMode.getInstance(java.lang.String,int,boolean)
        at com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError.abort(UserError.java:68)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.substitute.AnnotationSubstitutionProcessor.findOriginalMethod(AnnotationSubstitutionProcessor.java:637)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.substitute.AnnotationSubstitutionProcessor.handleMethodInAliasClass(AnnotationSubstitutionProcessor.java:330)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.substitute.AnnotationSubstitutionProcessor.handleAliasClass(AnnotationSubstitutionProcessor.java:302)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.substitute.AnnotationSubstitutionProcessor.handleClass(AnnotationSubstitutionProcessor.java:274)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.substitute.AnnotationSubstitutionProcessor.init(AnnotationSubstitutionProcessor.java:230)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.createDeclarativeSubstitutionProcessor(NativeImageGenerator.java:908)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.setupNativeImage(NativeImageGenerator.java:838)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:536)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.lambda$run$0(NativeImageGenerator.java:451)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1407)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:177)
Error: Image build request failed with exit status 1
```

pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.augusto.oauth2learning</groupId>
<artifactId>loginapp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus-plugin.version>1.7.1.Final</quarkus-plugin.version>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-universe-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>1.7.1.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</surefire-plugin.version>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
            <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
            <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jsonb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws.serverless</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-serverless-java-container-spring</artifactId>
        <version>[0.1,)</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-log4j2</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <version>1.4.199</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${quarkus-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare</goal>
                        <goal>prepare-tests</goal>
                        <goal>build</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                    <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>native</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>native</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                <goal>verify</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <systemPropertyVariables>
                                    <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                                    <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                                    <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                                </systemPropertyVariables>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        <properties>
            <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

application.properties

```
server.port=8081
quarkus.datasource.db-kind = h2
quarkus.datasource.username = sa
quarkus.datasource.password = password
quarkus.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.min-size=3
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.max-size=13
quarkus.datasource.driver =org.h2.Driver
quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=drop-and-create
```

Comment: Quarkus deprecated JDK 8 support with v1.6; I'd upgrade the JDK/GraalVM to something newer and try again.